# AWS SNS service SMS unsubscription

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SNS service to send the alert message to the users phone.However user unsubscribe to the topic still he gets the messages from that topic.To stop getting message user sending the message STOP .Following code snippet for creating and subscribing to topic.

```
CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(topicName);
CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = snsClient.createTopic(createTopicRequest);

//Topic display name
SetTopicAttributesRequest setTopicAttributesRequest = new SetTopicAttributesRequest();
setTopicAttributesRequest.withTopicArn(createTopicResult.getTopicArn());
setTopicAttributesRequest.setAttributeName(topicAttributeName);
setTopicAttributesRequest.setAttributeValue(topicAttributeValue);
snsClient.setTopicAttributes(setTopicAttributesRequest);

SubscribeRequest subRequest = new SubscribeRequest(createTopicResult.getTopicArn(), "sms","12712438216");
snsClient.subscribe(subRequest);
```

Comment: add complete details and related code..

Comment: @SaketMittal added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

1. List up all subscriptions
2. Loop until you find the endPoint("12712438216"), then get the arn
3. Execute the unsubscribe() function.

   ```
   ListSubscriptionsResult listResult = snsClient.listSubscriptions();
   List<Subscription> subscriptions = listResult.getSubscriptions();
   String arn="";
   for (Subscription subs : subscriptions) {
       if(subs.getProtocol().equals("sms") && subs.getEndpoint().equals("12712438216")) {
           arn = subs.getTopicArn();
           break;
       }
   }
   if(!arn.equals("")) {
       snsClient.unsubscribe(arn);
   }
   ```

Comment: that I can do with my application..However if user himself  do unsubscription request via sending the message STOP <TOPICNAME> to 30304.I can't track it right...

Comment: Yes, you can not track that.

Comment: is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with AWS SNS at the time this question was asked.